# React dangerouslySetInnerHTML Only Allow Specific HTML tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-rendering

In React, I need to take a JavaScript `String` and display it as HTML. I am using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to accomplish this, but I want to do this more safely by only allowing specific tags (e.g. `ul` and `li`). How can I accomplish this?

In the code below, I only want to allow the `ul` and `li` tags.

```
<p
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: '<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ul>'
}}></p>
```

When I try using `sanitizeHtml`, I get this:

```
./node_modules/sanitize-html/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (143:21)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Comment: From the available information, I would delegate the whole usage of dangerouslySetInnerHTML to a wrapper function, which will take at least 1 argument.

This one argument will be the element where I will be setting the HTML. 
From this wrapper function, I can write the logic to allow this execution to occur only for certain elements.

Share some sample code for better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

There is an open source library called [sanitize-html](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html#readme) that does exactly what you want. From their examples:

```js
// Allow only a super restricted set of tags and attributes
const clean = sanitizeHtml(dirty, {
  allowedTags: [ 'b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a' ],
  allowedAttributes: {
    'a': [ 'href' ]
  },
  allowedIframeHostnames: ['www.youtube.com']
});
```

Comment: How do I fix this error? `./node_modules/sanitize-html/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js         Module parse failed: Unexpected token (143:21)            You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Comment: @Alon Very hard to say without knowing more about your setup. It's webpack (create-react-app also uses webpack behind the scenes) complaining about some unsupported syntax in a file in postcss, which is a dependency of sanitize-html if it's any help.

Comment: You probably need to configure babel or similar.

Comment: @Alon Facing similar compilation issue. Is there any fix for it?

Comment: another popular package that does this https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify